# request.is_ajax() == True when clicking back button?

Tags: ajax, django

I have a Django app that returns different responses based on whether the page request is Ajax or not.

When I view a page, navigate elsewhere, then click the back button, the request gets rendered as if the value for `request.is_ajax()` is True. So the JSON output is showing up in the browser rather than the generated HTML.

Why might this be happening and how can I prevent it?

#### Clarifications

This is happening in Chrome (16.0.912.77)

Confusing matters is that I actually *am* making ajax requests of that URL in the background. Basically, I overloaded an URL so that it both displays the content in formatted HTML but also makes it available as JSON (so as changes happen overtime I can update the THML page in real time). It may be that the easiest solution, frustrating as it is, is to create a separate Django url pattern for the Ajax version.

Comment: I don't know Django, but could you check for the ajax parameters instead?

Comment: Are you are using some kind of javascript redirect from the previous page? such as window.location.href?

Comment: @Diodeus as far as I know, the way that it's detected is via a Header from the browser, as per Chris Patt's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164328/255918). There are no paramters being sent, I'm literally just requesting the same URL albeit via `jQuery.ajax()`.

Comment: @JamesR no, clicking on a link then hitting the back button.

Comment: I have the same issue. It's because the $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ] global is set. 
If I have the Chrome developer tools open while I hit back, then the $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ] global is empty, and it's fine.

Comment: Many years later: if you're stuck on this, the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20640957/5368039 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax):

> Returns True if the request was made via an `XMLHttpRequest`, by
>   checking the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header for the string
>   'XMLHttpRequest'.

So the question is really why does pressing the back button attach that header to the request? That doesn't seem like appropriate behavior in any browser. So, which browser(s) have you tried this on? Do they all have the same behavior? If not, which addons do you have installed in the offending browser that might cause such an issue?

**EDIT**

You don't necessarily have to create an entirely separate view and/or urlpattern, but it might not be a bad idea to use a query string. In REST it's not uncommon for the same view to return multiple different formats, but this is usually done like:

```
http://domain.com/some/view/      # Returns HTML
http://domain.com/some/view/?json # Returns JSON
```

It's a small compromise that might be enough to get around your issue.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified: it's happening in Chrome. I'll make that note in the question; haven't actually tested it out in other browsers to see if it's the same on all of them. And, frustratingly, it doesn't *always* do it.

Comment: I'll look into using the query string as a solution; however, it's annoying that I have to check for this rather than just determining if it's an Ajax request or not. Means I might have to rewrite a fair amount of code. The reason I'm actually leaning towards URL patterns is that I don't have to change my code at all. I'm guessing that the browser is caching the jQuery ajax request for the URL and returning it when I hit the back button. If I give it a different URL that will probably fix it, without having to replace `request.is_ajax()` with if `request.REQUEST.get('json')==True`.