# Django is_ajax history back

Tags: python, ajax, django, jquery, django-views

I wrote a Django view that responses ether a `text/html` or a `application/json` depending on `request.is_ajax()`.
So far so good, but when I use my browsers history buttons, I end up getting a JSON response rather than the HTML.

I can't figure out the problem. It's true an jQuery ajax request is getting the same url after the page was loaded, but that shouldn't end up in the history, or should it?

Thanks, Joe

Comment: My hunch is that the browser cache is the actual problem. If you go back and reload, does it load the html version? Likewise, if you clear your browser cache directly before going back, does it load HTML or JSON?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you send different content depending on `request.is_ajax()`, you need to send `Vary: X-Requested-With` to the browser. That way, the browser will be able to distinguish the two kinds of response based on the value of the `X-Requested-With` header on the request. You can do that via:

```
from django.views.decorators.vary import vary_on_headers

@vary_on_headers('X-Requested-With')
def yourview(request, ...):
    pass
```