# Django - redirecting back to a page shows http response (Json data) and not rendering

Tags: python, jquery, html, json, django

**Question: What would be the best way of dealing with this so that the json response isn't shown if the user redirects like this? Or to take the user back to the state of the quiz before the data is retrieved?**

Bit of an awkward one to explain. I'm creating a quiz application using django. A user can select a quiz to undertake, when they select what quiz they are taken to the following page:
(Screenshot 1)
[image: Quiz Start]

When the quiz is started, an ajax request is sent to the back end to retrieve the questions for the quiz and display them to the user. The problem is if the quiz is already started and I use the browsers back button and then reload the page it shows the json response instead of (Screenshot 1) it shows:

**Json Response**:

[image: Json]

**View.py**

```
def active_quiz(request, quiz_pk):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(pk=quiz_pk)

    questions = Questions.objects.filter(quiz=quiz_pk)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method =="GET":
            serial = serializers.serialize("json", Questions.objects.filter(quiz=quiz_pk))

            response_data = serial
            return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")

    args={'question': questions, 'quiz': quiz}
    return render(request, 'quiz/quiz_active.html', args
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is probably not the answer you are expecting but you should **split** your views, and create two different endpoints for API and rendering purpose.

Also, can you take a look at this ?

[request.is_ajax() == True when clicking back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163588/request-is-ajax-true-when-clicking-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `JsonResponse` instead of `HttpResponse`. It'll go to your ajax.

```
return JsonResponse(json_object, safe=False)
```

Comment: Using JsonResponse still produces the same json data but in string format, it doesn't solve the issue of mitigating the json data being viewable by the user upon redirecting back and forth with the browser. Cheers - Darren